Linux bridge forwarding specific udp message to local process for correction
I have been trying to set up a Linux machine with a Bridge using brctl, and then using iptables to forward a specific set of udp messages to a local process. I have a test set up of three PC's, "Client - Bridge - Server" that are on the same subnet 192.168.1.0.
[** Edit 9 Sep 2024 - Set enp1s0 and enp3s0 with IP Addresses based on Tom's recommendation. Also used different machine with Ubuntu Linux installed **]
 11 ===============           ==================           ================
 12 | Raspberry PI|           |Linux Ubuntu PC |           | Windows PC   |
 13 | [Client ]   |           | [Bridge]       |           | [Server]     |
 14 | 192.168.1.1 |<--------->|enp1s0    enp3s0|---------->| 192.168.1.10 |
 15 |             |           |(..1.40)(..1.41)|           |              |
 16 | nc -4 -u    |           |nc -4 -u -l     |           |ncat -4 -u    |
 17 | 192.168.1.10|           |127.0.0.1 2300  |           |192.168.1.10  |
 18 | 2300        |           |                |           |2300          |
 19 ===============           ==================           ================

The wireless LANs on each machine are not shown. (192.168.3.X)
After extensive research of this site, and many manual pages and other resources I am unable to get the messages routed to the bridge PC local process.
The must be something simple I am missing. Any assistance would be very appreciated.
From my research the message packet flow I was thinking it would follow based on Netfilter-packet-flow diagram in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter is shown below in Fig1.

Start ..... then (Link Layer:) bridge.[nat.prerouting] -> network.[raw.prerouting] -> Link.[Conntrack] -> network.[mangle.prerouting] -> network.[nat.prerouting]->link.[bridging decision]
-> bridge.[filter.input]-> (Network Layer:) network.[routing decision] -> network.[mangle.input]
-> network.[nat.input]-> network.[filter.input]-> (Protocol Layer:) protocol.[xfm/socket lookup]-> (Application Layer:) -> [LOCAL PROCESS] 


Conntrack is reporting the packet from 192.168.1.1 on the first arrival.
Packet counters are incrementing on -t nat PREROUTING.
No increments on Filter Input count. Unable to find where packets are being dropped.
Wireshark is showing packets arriving on enp1s0.
Ping is working between Server and Client in both directions.
Kernal log is showing only iptables nat PREROUTING log message only.

Again any assistance would be appreciated.
Summary of set up after many attempts using different approaches using iptables  PREROUTING rules with jumps using DNAT and REDIRECT (REDIRECT is Current configuration)
** RP 2 Sep 2024 : Updated with new iptables log messages and results (no change) plus image showing route expecting through netfilter**
[Edit 9 Sep 2023 : updated with new iptables log messages and results *** that are now working *** (Thanks to Tom for helping with the details on which to focus. ) ]
1.1 Bridge Configuration: 
---------------------

root@unbuntu:/proc/sys/net/bridge# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br2             8000.9e97a16a319d       no              enp1s0
                                                        enp3s0

1.2 Ifconfig:
-------------
root@ubuntu:/proc/sys/net/bridge# ifconfig
br2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9c97:a1ff:fe6a:319d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9e:97:a1:6a:31:9d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14034  bytes 1202079 (1.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 44  bytes 4865 (4.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.40  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::2f1:f5ff:fe2e:9ca6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:f1:f5:2e:9c:a6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3869  bytes 3171892 (3.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25757  bytes 2107675 (2.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.41  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::2f1:f5ff:fe2e:9ca5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:f1:f5:2e:9c:a5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26080  bytes 2306928 (2.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 964  bytes 139133 (139.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7327  bytes 643895 (643.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7327  bytes 643895 (643.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

1.3 iptables set up
1.3.1 Final set up
root@ubuntu:/proc/sys/net/bridge# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.10 (nf_tables) on Sun Sep  8 21:16:46 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [4109:1182575]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [2880:185759]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2181:1036799]
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j LOG --log-prefix "Fil FOR 0/0 P3300" --log-level 7
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j LOG --log-prefix "Fil FOR .0.1 P3300" --log-level 7
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 33000 -j LOG --log-prefix "Fil Inp 0/0 P33000: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 33000 -j LOG --log-prefix "Fil INP .0.1 P33000: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 2300 -j LOG --log-prefix "Fil INP .0.1 P2300: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 2300 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 33000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 2300 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 33000 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j LOG --log-prefix "Fil FOR 0/0 P3300" --log-level 7
-A FORWARD -p udp -m udp --dport 33000 -j LOG --log-prefix "Fil FOR 0/0 P33000" --log-level 7
-A FORWARD -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 2300 -j LOG --log-prefix "Fil FOR .0.1 P2300: " --log-level 7
-A FORWARD -p udp -m udp --dport 2300 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p udp -m udp --dport 33000 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep  8 21:16:46 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.10 (nf_tables) on Sun Sep  8 21:16:46 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2729:367576]
:INPUT ACCEPT [126:14962]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [127:11321]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1907:110254]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.10/32 -i br2 -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j LOG --log-prefix "nat Pre 1.10 P3300" --log-level 7
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.10/32 -i br2 -p udp -m physdev --physdev-in enp1s0 -m udp --dport 3300 -j LOG --log-prefix "nat Pre enp1s0 P3300" --log-level 7
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.10/32 -i br2 -p udp -m udp --dport 2300 -j LOG --log-prefix "nat Pre 1.10 P2300" --log-level 7
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.10/32 -i br2 -p udp -m physdev --physdev-in enp1s0 -m udp --dport 2300 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 2300
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.10/32 -i br2 -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3300
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 2300 -j LOG --log-prefix "nat Inp 0/0 P2300" --log-level 7
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j LOG --log-prefix "nat Inp 0.1 P3300" --log-level 7
-A INPUT -d 192.168.1.10/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j LOG --log-prefix "nat Inp 1.10 P3300" --log-level 7
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 33000 -j LOG --log-prefix "nat Inp 0/0 P33000: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 33000 -j LOG --log-prefix "nat Inp .0.1 P33000: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 3300 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 33000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 2300 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

# Completed on Sun Sep  8 21:16:46 2024

1.3.3 IPTABLES Counters (***working ***)
root@ubuntu:/proc/sys/net/bridge# iptables -t nat -L -vn --line-numbers
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2844 packets, 385K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        4   126 LOG        17   --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.10         udp dpt:3300 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "nat Pre 1.10 P3300"
2        4   126 LOG        17   --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.10         PHYSDEV match --physdev-in enp1s0 udp dpt:3300 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "nat Pre enp1s0 P3300"
3        1    36 LOG        17   --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.10         udp dpt:2300 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "nat Pre 1.10 P2300"
4        1    36 REDIRECT   17   --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.10         PHYSDEV match --physdev-in enp1s0 udp dpt:2300 redir ports 2300
5        4   126 DNAT       17   --  br2    *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.10         udp dpt:3300 to:127.0.0.1:3300

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 133 packets, 15519 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 LOG        17   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:2300 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "nat Inp 0/0 P2300"
2        2    65 LOG        17   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            udp dpt:3300 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "nat Inp 0.1 P3300"
3        0     0 LOG        17   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.10         udp dpt:3300 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "nat Inp 1.10 P3300"
4        0     0 LOG        17   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:33000 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "nat Inp 0/0 P33000: "
5        0     0 LOG        17   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            udp dpt:33000 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "nat Inp .0.1 P33000: "
6        2    65 ACCEPT     17   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3300
7        0     0 ACCEPT     17   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:33000
8        0     0 ACCEPT     17   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:2300

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 132 packets, 11690 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1982 packets, 115K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

1.4 Kernal Log
Test Conducted on Client (192.168.1.1)
 root@pi:/home/system# nc -4 -u 192.168.1.10 3300
1
11
111

&&
root@pi:/home/system# nc -4 -u 192.168.1.10 2300
1
11
111

root@pi:/home/system# 

1.4.1 Original Kernal Log
2024-09-02T03:35:20.464377+00:00 mint kernel: iwl data: 00000000: 94 02 00 40 2b 99 8f 1b d9 7c 7d c1 69 6c 3a 86  ...@+....|}.il:.
2024-09-02T03:35:20.464378+00:00 mint kernel: iwl data: 00000010: 24 c2 94 1f 04 48 5d 53 68 8d 76 60 42 c3 97 4f  $....H]Sh.v`B..O
2024-09-02T04:07:32.702194+00:00 mint kernel: PREROUTING INPUT : IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp3s0 MAC=08:60:6e:06:59:4c:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.10 LEN=35 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40572 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44428 DPT=2300 LEN=15 

1.4.2 Updated Kernal Log - 3 sep 2024
Includes additional log messages in iptables and includes using DNAT and REROUTING to investigate if two methods make any difference to routing to local process in kernal.
2024-09-03T02:34:52.992698+00:00 mint kernel: nat Prerouting 1.10 Port 3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp3s0 MAC=08:60:6e:06:59:4c:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.10 LEN=30 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60380 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=58359 DPT=3300 LEN=10 
2024-09-03T02:34:52.992727+00:00 mint kernel: nat Prerouting enp3s0 Port 33IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp3s0 MAC=08:60:6e:06:59:4c:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.10 LEN=30 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60380 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=58359 DPT=3300 LEN=10 
2024-09-03T02:34:54.532861+00:00 mint kernel: nat Prerouting 1.10 Port 3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp3s0 MAC=08:60:6e:06:59:4c:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.10 LEN=31 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60381 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=58359 DPT=3300 LEN=11 
2024-09-03T02:34:54.532894+00:00 mint kernel: nat Prerouting enp3s0 Port 33IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp3s0 MAC=08:60:6e:06:59:4c:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.10 LEN=31 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60381 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=58359 DPT=3300 LEN=11 
2024-09-03T02:34:58.714176+00:00 mint kernel: nat Prerouting 1.10 Port 3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp3s0 MAC=08:60:6e:06:59:4c:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.10 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60382 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=58359 DPT=3300 LEN=12 
2024-09-03T02:34:58.714210+00:00 mint kernel: nat Prerouting enp3s0 Port 33IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp3s0 MAC=08:60:6e:06:59:4c:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.10 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60382 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=58359 DPT=3300 LEN=12 

1.4.3 *** Working *** Kernal Log - 9 Sep 2024
2024-09-08T22:09:21.657478-04:00 ubuntu kernel: nat Pre 1.10 P3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp1s0 MAC=08:60:6e:06:59:4c:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.10 LEN=30 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43632 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41488 DPT=3300 LEN=10 2024-09-08T22:09:21.657498-04:00 ubuntu kernel: nat Pre enp1s0 P3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp1s0 MAC=08:60:6e:06:59:4c:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.10 LEN=30 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43632 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41488 DPT=3300 LEN=10 2024-09-08T22:09:21.657499-04:00 ubuntu kernel: Fil FOR 0/0 P3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp1s0 MAC=9e:97:a1:6a:31:9d:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=30 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43632 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41488 DPT=3300 LEN=10 2024-09-08T22:09:21.657500-04:00 ubuntu kernel: Fil FOR .0.1 P3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp1s0 MAC=9e:97:a1:6a:31:9d:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=30 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43632 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41488 DPT=3300 LEN=10 2024-09-08T22:09:21.657500-04:00 ubuntu kernel: nat Inp 0.1 P3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp1s0 MAC=9e:97:a1:6a:31:9d:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=30 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43632 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41488 DPT=3300 LEN=10 2024-09-08T22:09:22.609485-04:00 ubuntu kernel: Fil FOR 0/0 P3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp1s0 MAC=9e:97:a1:6a:31:9d:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=31 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43633 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41488 DPT=3300 LEN=11 2024-09-08T22:09:22.609502-04:00 ubuntu kernel: Fil FOR .0.1 P3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp1s0 MAC=9e:97:a1:6a:31:9d:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=31 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43633 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41488 DPT=3300 LEN=11 2024-09-08T22:09:24.026286-04:00 ubuntu kernel: Fil FOR 0/0 P3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp1s0 MAC=9e:97:a1:6a:31:9d:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43634 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41488 DPT=3300 LEN=12 2024-09-08T22:09:24.026304-04:00 ubuntu kernel: Fil FOR .0.1 P3300IN=br2 OUT= PHYSIN=enp1s0 MAC=9e:97:a1:6a:31:9d:dc:a6:32:aa:48:c5:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43634 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41488 DPT=3300 LEN=12

------------------------------------------------------------------------

1.5 Local Process - Linux Mint PC Listening command:
root@mint:/home/mint# nc -l -4 -u 127.0.0.1 33000

    (no responses displayed)

& in separate terminal window.
root@mint:/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf# nc -l -4 -u 127.0.0.1 3300

(no responses displayed)

1.5.1 Local Process [9 Sep 2024]- Ubuntu PC Listening (** that is working **) Command:
root@ubuntu:/home/system# nc -l -4 -u 127.0.0.1 3300
1
11
111

1.6 sysctl settings (relevent)
*** Original Set up removed due to character limit of article ***
[EDIT 9 Sep 2024] 1.6.1 Working sysctl settings:
root@ubuntu:/proc/sys/net/bridge# sysctl .net.ipv4.conf.br2
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.accept_local = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.accept_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.accept_source_route = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.arp_accept = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.arp_announce = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.arp_evict_nocarrier = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.arp_filter = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.arp_ignore = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.arp_notify = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.bc_forwarding = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.bootp_relay = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.disable_policy = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.disable_xfrm = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.force_igmp_version = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.forwarding = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.log_martians = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.mc_forwarding = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.medium_id = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.promote_secondaries = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.proxy_arp = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0


.net.ipv4.conf.br2.route_localnet = 1


.net.ipv4.conf.br2.rp_filter = 0


.net.ipv4.conf.br2.secure_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.send_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.shared_media = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.src_valid_mark = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.br2.tag = 0


.net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_local = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_accept = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_announce = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_evict_nocarrier = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_filter = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_notify = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.bc_forwarding = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.bootp_relay = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.disable_policy = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.disable_xfrm = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.force_igmp_version = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.default.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
.net.ipv4.conf.default.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
.net.ipv4.conf.default.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.medium_id = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.promote_secondaries = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.route_localnet = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
.net.ipv4.conf.default.secure_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.default.shared_media = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.default.src_valid_mark = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.default.tag = 0


.net.ipv4.udp_child_hash_entries = 0
.net.ipv4.udp_early_demux = 1
.net.ipv4.udp_hash_entries = 8192
.net.ipv4.udp_l3mdev_accept = 0
.net.ipv4.udp_mem = 374430  499242  748860
.net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 4096
.net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 4096
.net.ipv4.xfrm4_gc_thresh = 32768


root@ubuntu:/proc/sys/net/bridge# sysctl .net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.accept_local = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.accept_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.accept_source_route = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_accept = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_announce = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_evict_nocarrier = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_filter = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_ignore = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.arp_notify = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.bc_forwarding = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.bootp_relay = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.disable_policy = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.disable_xfrm = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.force_igmp_version = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.forwarding = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.log_martians = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.mc_forwarding = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.medium_id = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.promote_secondaries = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.proxy_arp = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.route_localnet = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.rp_filter = 2
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.secure_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.send_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.shared_media = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.src_valid_mark = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.tag = 0

root@ubuntu:/proc/sys/net/bridge# sysctl .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.accept_local = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.accept_redirects = 1
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.accept_source_route = 1
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_accept = 1
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_announce = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_evict_nocarrier = 1
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_filter = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_ignore = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.arp_notify = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.bc_forwarding = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.bootp_relay = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.disable_policy = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.disable_xfrm = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.force_igmp_version = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.forwarding = 1
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.log_martians = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.mc_forwarding = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.medium_id = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.promote_secondaries = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.proxy_arp = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.route_localnet = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.rp_filter = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.secure_redirects = 1
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.send_redirects = 1
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.shared_media = 1
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.src_valid_mark = 0
    .net.ipv4.conf.enp3s0.tag = 0

root@ubuntu:/proc/sys/net/bridge# sysctl .net.ipv4.conf.all
.net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_local = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_accept = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_evict_nocarrier = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_notify = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.bc_forwarding = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.bootp_relay = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.disable_policy = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.disable_xfrm = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.force_igmp_version = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.all.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
.net.ipv4.conf.all.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
.net.ipv4.conf.all.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.medium_id = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.all.shared_media = 1
.net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark = 0
.net.ipv4.conf.all.tag = 0

** Last Critical Change that made it work for the first time ***
   root@ubuntu:/proc/sys/net/bridge# sysctl -w .net.ipv4.conf.br2.rp_filter=0
    .net.ipv4.conf.br2.rp_filter = 0


iptables does care about packet that does not egress from the bridge to the host (except when br_netfilter is loaded and the bridge-nf-call-iptables sysctl is 1, but even then I think only the filtering rules would be checked). In other words in the "normal" circumstances, the REDIRECT rule would only be applied if this hosts is used as gateway, which is usually not the case when two hosts in the same LAN. Besides, your bridge doesn't even have an IP configured on it, so there's pretty much no way the host is acting as the gateway for any traffics.)

You might want to either force the traffics to egress from the bridge to the host by using an indirect route for even 192.168.1.0/24 on the other two hosts (with the gateway/nexthop of that route being the IP configured on the bridge). (You should probably use a netmask of 255.255.255.255 in that case, so that no direct route would be implicitly added.) It can probably be achieved with the help of an nftables bridge table instead (of the necessary routes), where you can simply overwrite the destination MAC address of the corresponding frames with set ether daddr.)

(I meant "does NOT care" in my first comment.)

Also you would really want to configure an IP on the bridge and listen to that IP with either approach. REDIRECT might not work properly without the former, and "forcefully" DNATing to 127.0.0.1 might still lead to other complication (e.g. route_localnet)

Thank you Tom for taking the time to answer. I'l lreconfigure the ethernets with an IP address, and I was checking which modules were loaded in the kernal using lsmod to verify if any kernal modules had not been loaded. I noted that iptables is loaded and everyhting else if nf_xxxx versus ip_xxxx. e.g. ip_conntrack in the Linux Mint version I'm running.

Thanks again Tom, I did end up moving back to my original machine that had ubuntu installed. The two ethernets were updated with IP addresses. After focusing on the settings based on your comments the iptables LOG and PREROUTING statements wer checked / tweaked e.g. FORWARD and route_localnet at the bridge level as well as the ethernet  interfaces.  One of the key settings was the bridge rp_filter. When set to 0 it seemed to come alive. I have updated the article with the working details. Thanks again.

After going back to testing using port 2300 I found that it is the DNAT rule that works reliably for routing the UDP messages from the bridge to the local machine (versus the REDIRECT).
